# Troubles to open ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to open a `ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender` with `JavaScript` but when I run my code and I call the function from the code behind this crash and show this error.

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'show' of undefined
>   or null reference

this is my `JavaScript`:

```
<script>
    function closeChangeArea() {
        $find('ModalChangeArea').hide();
    }

    function showChangeArea() {
        $find('ModalChangeArea').show();
    }
</script>
```

and this is my code:

```
protected void Btn_Click_Ch_Area(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;
            GridViewRow gr = (GridViewRow)lb.NamingContainer;

            Label ToolChange = (Label)gr.FindControl("Lbl_toolg");
            Txt_Tool_Reasign.Text = ToolChange.Text;

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "showChangeArea();", true);
        }
```

this is my `ModalPoupExtender`

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender
        ID="ModalChangeArea"
        runat="server"
        TargetControlID="hid"
        PopupControlID="ChangeArea"
        RepositionMode="RepositionOnWindowResizeAndScroll"
        DropShadow="true"
        PopupDragHandleControlID="moveArea">
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In asp.net control id is dynamically appended with container, in that case you will not get the control using $find to get control use clientid of asp.net control or set ClientIdMode = "Static".

Try below code to access element.

```
$find('<%= ModalChangeArea.ClientID %>').show();
$find('<%= ModalChangeArea.ClientID %>').hide();
```

Comment: the `ClientIdMode = "Static"` works for me, thank you very much!